# Add parameter to function reference when passing it as parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm working in a callback-chained project and I've hit a point that can easily be solved by creating an annonymous function.

This is the code I have:

```
let firstValue = 3;
let secondValue = 4;
setInterval(() => { 
    sumTheValues(firstValue, secondValue);
}, 10);
```

What I wanted to do is to execute `sumTheValues` with `firstValue` and `secondValue` after the 10ms interval.

I know in some cases you can use `.bind` so the `this` inside of the function will have your variable's value is, but that wouldn't work for me.
As I said, it can be easily resolved by passing an annonymous function's reference, but I was wondering if Javascript would have something that could natively add parameters to this callback.

Comment: it's built in: [`var intervalID = scope.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: Yes, I realize now that setInterval was a poor choice of an example, but it was just to illustrate a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to `setInterval` which will passed along to your callback:

```
setInterval(sumTheValues, 10, firstValue, secondValue);
```

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

---

However, there is a difference between doing that and using a closure (as you do in your question):

- When passing the arguments directly to `setInterval`, the values/variables are evaluated once, so `sumTheValues` will always receive the same values.
- When using a closure, `firstValue` and `secondValue` are re-evaluated every time the function is called, so if their values changed in the meantime, `sumTheValues` will get different values.

Comment: firstValue and SecondValue's value not being update is completely fine in this case. And indeed, setInterval CAN reveive multiple arguments, which will serve as my callback function's parameters. I just used setInterval because it was the smallest example I could think of, but in fact I want to use them as callback to other functions that wouldn't have this behaviour.